# Unoffical Skyrim Patch: How do I test if it's installed and working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I recently bought Skyrim for PC. I have installed the SkyUI mod which is working fine. I also want to use the Unofficial Skyrim Patch mod, because it fixes tons of stuff in the game.

I've got the USKP mod files coppied to my data folder, and have it set as the first mod to load (SkyUI is my only other mod). But, one of the fixes (Argonians no longer gasp when leaving water, because they're water-breathers anyway) doesn't actually seem to have been applied.

I can't seem to find any way in-game to tell if the USKP mod is actually loaded and working or not. Is there any specific way I can test if it's working? Or anyway to tell the difference between just that one fix not being applied, and the whole mod not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Argonians no longer gasp when leaving water' USKP fix is affected by the issues described in [this USKP thread post in the Bethesda forums](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1396806-wiprelz-unofficial-skyrim-patch-thread-10/page__view__findpost__p__21231769):

> Skyrim Patch 1.6.89 introduced one critically bad bug:
>
> Edited vanilla dialogue causes the audio and subtitles to fail to display. Papyrus fragments attached to failed dialogue will also fail to execute.
>
> As a result, ALL edits to dialogue of any sort have been removed.
>
> A temporary update for the USKP has been issued to address this, but it isn't entirely without use as several other bugs which can be safely fixed have been.

An easy game mechanic check to see if USKP is working is this (from v1.0 - 2012-04-07):

> NPCs will no longer drop weapons or shields as separate objects, as these are never cleaned up which greatly adds to save bloating and litters the gameworld (the items will still appear to be dropped, but will access the corpse's inventory to be taken and be cleaned up with the corpse if left)

For other USKP changes you can check, see the [Complete list of USKP fixes](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Legendary%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html).

Comment: @desaivv NP and thanks. I had it for some time now. I played too much Skyrim back then. =)

Comment: Link to complete list is dead

Comment: @ppperry Fixed.

Comment: Link to complete list is dead again.

Comment: @pppery Fixed (again).